# Proving something is NOT a tensor

Tags: mathematical-physics, tensors, general-relativity, index-notation

I need to show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}v^{j}(x)$ is not a tensor.

Here $v^i(x)$ is a vector field. I tried writing down the tensor transformation like this:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x'^{i'}}}v'^{j'}(x')=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x'^{i'}} \frac{\partial x'^{j'}}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}v^{j}(x)$$

And thus I think this looks like a tensor transformation is supposed to look. I've likely done something incorrectly, could someone please give me a hint here on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The language is sloppy. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} v^{j}$ is obviously not a tensor, but the components of a tensor-like object on a manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you went wrong is that you don't write the derivation correctly. What you must do is this

$$
\frac{\partial v^{j'}}{\partial x^{i'}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i'}} v^{j'} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{i'}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}_\text{by chain rule} \underbrace{\Bigg( \frac{\partial x^{j'}}{\partial x^j} v^j   \Bigg) }_\text{by transf.rule for $v^{j'}$} = \dots (\text{proceed})
$$
which is by chain rule and tensor transformation rule $\textbf{for}$ $v^{j'}$.  Proceed by yourself and find out why its not a tensor.

Comment: So basically I need to take the derivative of  the two terms and therefore by product rule, I arrive that this is not the same as I've wrote down in my original expression, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.